# Select database entity depending of one of its datetime columns value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have table `article` in the database. The table contains `Date Expiration` column, which can be null.

I want to select article if it's not expired. I've got the following code, but unfortunately, it does not work.

```
var lstArticle = (from a in Articles.ToList()
                  where a.Block == false
                        && a.DateExpiration < DateTime.Now
                  select a).ToList();
```

plases help me

Edit:

i use this code, and this working.

```
var lstArticle = (from a in Articles.ToList()
                  where a.Block == false
                        && ((!a.DateExpiration.HasValue) || (a.DateExpiration.HasValue && a.DateExpiration.Value < DateTime.Now))
                  select a).ToList();
```

Comment: If date s null, how do you want to handle it? You can try converting it to null and do your filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If no date means the item has not expired, this should do the trick:

```
var lstArticle = (from a in Articles.ToList()
                  where a.Block == false
                        && (!a.DateExpiration.HasValue || a.DateExpiration < DateTime.Now)
                  select a).ToList();
```

<del>If no date means the item has expired, this should work:</del> (Based on your comments you need the first example)

```
var lstArticle = (from a in Articles.ToList()
                  where a.Block == false
                        && (a.DateExpiration.HasValue && a.DateExpiration < DateTime.Now)
                  select a).ToList();
```

I have just noticed, you do not need the "new" keyword in your select statement if you are selecting the exact objects from the source.

Comment: The first example will select articles with a null DateExpiration.  The second example will not select articles with a null DateExpiration.

Comment: i edit this. but with your code, not selectd article with null DateExpiration. Just selected article which a.DateExpiration.HasValue

Comment: i want select DateExpiration is null and a.DateExpiration < DateTime.Now

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your requirements, the first example is what you need.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26123/discussion-between-babak-saeedi-and-oliver)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `DateExpiration` is a `DateTime?`, use this:

```
var lstArticle =
    (from a in Articles.ToList()
     where a.Block == false
        && a.DateExpiration.HasValue
        && a.DateExpiration.Value < DateTime.Now
     select new a).ToList();
```

Comment: with this code, no selected article with null Date Expiration

Comment: @BabakSaeedi What do you want the behavior to be when `DateExpiration` is `null`?

Comment: if DateExpiration is null so select this

Comment: @BabakSaeedi then use **oliver**'s fist suggestion. It will work perfectly in your situation